# Basic Solutions and Linear Optimization

Tags: linear-programming

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  1&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  1&  1&  0& 0\\ 
 0&  0&  1&  -1& 1
\end{bmatrix}

This problem is related to Linear Optimization where this matrix is labelled as Coefficient Matrix A and I am expected to find all the basic solutions to this Matrix A. 5 Variables and 3 equality constraints, so there will be 2 Non - Basic Variables and 3 Basic Variables. I do know that we need only Linearly independent columns in order to form bases as part of the basic solutions, but I don't know how you would easily group all the linearly independent columns together.

Like the solution to this problem says that Columns 1, 4, and 5 are linearly dependent and any 3 of the last 4 columns are also linearly dependent, so you would not form bases from them.

But is there some shortcut or trick that can be applied to quickly determine which of the column vectors are dependent so that I can take them out while solving this type of problem?

Comment: Your matrix is already in upper triangular form. So there is no short cut.

Comment: I know that the last 2 column vectors are Linearly dependent, but then I have more than 7 combos of 3 other vectors to check if they are Linearly Independent/Dependent....

You mean just slog it through and check all cases..?

Comment: It is upper triangular. It rather easy to see if a submatrix is singular or not.

Comment: You may left out the last the column. Swap it with the 4th column in each basis...